# 2 foreach loops tripling submitted data

Tags: php

I have 3 hidden fields and 3 text fields. I need to loop through both to UPDATE database records. If I use the foreach loops separately, it posts 3 values correctly. If I try use them together it seems to triple the text input value which is a date. So instead of looking like this:

1 - 2017-04-05
2 - 2017-04-06
3 - 2017-04-07

It looks like this:

1 - 2017-04-05
2 - 2017-04-05
3 - 2017-04-05
1 - 2017-04-06
2 - 2017-04-06
3 - 2017-04-06
1 - 2017-04-07
2 - 2017-04-07
3 - 2017-04-07

```
        foreach($_POST['commit_date'] as $commitdate) {
            foreach($_POST['unit'] as $units) {

                echo $units .= $commitdate . "<br/>";

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use the foreach loops separately, it posts 3 values correctly. If I try use them together it seems to triple the text input value which is a date.

That's because you're using nested `foreach` loops, which means for each outer loop, inner loop will be executed thrice. And that's why you're getting 9 values.

Instead, use a simple `for` loop like this,

```
$count = count($_POST['unit']);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i){
    echo $_POST['unit'][$i] .= $_POST['commit_date'][$i] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try that now and get back to you shortly

Comment: thank you! I have struggling with this for ages and all I had to do was change the loop. Can't believe it!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are posting `unit` and `commit_date` with size `3`

```
   foreach($_POST['commit_date'] as $commitdate) { \\ this will iterate 3
        foreach($_POST['unit'] as $units) { \\ this will iterate 9 times

            echo $units .= $commitdate . "<br/>";

        }
    }
```

You will see output as below:

```
**First Iteration**
1 - 2017-04-05
2 - 2017-04-05
3 - 2017-04-05

**Second Iteration**
1 - 2017-04-06
2 - 2017-04-06
3 - 2017-04-06

**Third Iteration**
1 - 2017-04-07
2 - 2017-04-07
3 - 2017-04-07
```

Comment: Why does the second one iterate 9 times? It should only iterate 3 times like the first foreach statement

Comment: because 3x3 . For first iteration of outer loop, inner loop will execute 3 time same for 2nd and 3rd.